# Problem when using v-slide-group with few items

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm having a problem with v-slide-group, sometimes I have 2~3 items and sometimes I have 10 items or more, but with fewer items it doesn't show the arrows neither the slide-items are centered
Here is my HTML:

```
    <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-sheet
    elevation="8"
    class="mx-auto mt-10"
    max-width="700"
  >
    <v-slide-group
      multiple
      show-arrows
    >
      <v-slide-item
        v-for="n in 25"
        :key="n"
        v-slot="{ active, toggle }"
      >
        <v-btn
          class="mx-2"
          :input-value="active"
          active-class="purple white--text"
          depressed
          rounded
          @click="toggle"
        >
          Options {{ n }}
        </v-btn>
      </v-slide-item>
    </v-slide-group>
      <v-slide-group
      multiple
      show-arrows
    >
      <v-slide-item
        v-for="n in 3"
        :key="n"
        v-slot="{ active, toggle }"
      >
        <v-btn
          class="mx-2"
          :input-value="active"
          active-class="purple white--text"
          depressed
          rounded
          @click="toggle"
        >
          Options {{ n }}
        </v-btn>
      </v-slide-item>
    </v-slide-group>
  </v-sheet>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

and here is my JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    model: null,
  }),
  methods:{

  }
})
```

I also made this codepen: https://codepen.io/mastergoshi/pen/rNwYJGz

How can I at least center the slide items from the second slide-group?
Even better would be to show the arrows as well with the slide-items centered

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

In order to center the slide you can use below css:

```
.v-slide-group__content {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

You can see example in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/nimaebrazeh/pen/YzQEoKo).

According to vuetify docs:

> By default, arrows always display on Desktop when the container is overflowing.

So if you want to show the arrows you should reduce the size of wrapper container. Otherwise vuetify doesn't show the arrows.

Answer (score 2):

from the doc for the `show-arrows` prop we have:

> Change when the overflow arrow indicators are shown. By default, arrows always display on Desktop when the container is overflowing. When the container overflows on mobile, arrows are not shown by default. A show-arrows value of true allows these arrows to show on Mobile if the container overflowing. A value of desktop always displays arrows on Desktop while a value of mobile always displays arrows on Mobile. A value of always always displays arrows on Desktop and Mobile.

so setting `show-arrows="always"` on `v-slide-group` resolves the arrows visibility issue.

to center the `v-slide-item`s simply put them in a row like:

```
<v-row justify="center" align="center" class="my-1">
 <v-slide-item></v-slide-item>
</v-row>
```

check out the demo below:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-slide-group multiple show-arrows="always">
          <v-row justify="center" align="center" class="my-1">
            <v-slide-item v-for="n in 3" :key="n" v-slot="{ active, toggle }">
              <v-btn class="mx-2" :input-value="active" active-class="purple white--text" depressed rounded @click="toggle">
                Options {{ n }}
              </v-btn>
            </v-slide-item>
          </v-row>
        </v-slide-group>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried show-arrows="always" on my codepen and it didn't work, do you know why?

Comment: @Tailsk1 I checked your codepen. it is throwing prop type check error where it only accepts `boolean` for `show-arrows` and when I checked vuetify version used in the codepen, found that it is using `vuetify@2.0.19` so it is possible that accepting `always` as a prop is a recent feature added some time after `vuetify@2.0.19`. vuetify doc is currently at `v2.5.8`