# I used v-slider-group. The arrows on the sides are not visible when the page is first loaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I used v-slider-group. The arrows on the sides are not visible when the page is first loaded. When I increase or decrease the page size, the arrows start to appear. After this process, it also appears in the first dimension of the page. But it does not appear without making any changes.

```
      v-if="!loading && myEducationsFiltered.length>0 && listType !== 'requested'"

      v-model="modelMyEdu"
      active-class="success"
      class="pa-4"
      show-arrows>

      <v-slide-item
        v-for="(item,index) in myEducationsFiltered.slice(0, 7)"
        :key="index">
       <course.........>
      </v-slide-item>
 </v-slide-group>
```

Comment: does this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69201323/problem-when-using-v-slide-group-with-few-items/69203182#69203182